# How do i use cron to update a file in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

So I have this github repo that updates every 24 hours and I want to pull a file every 24 hours; from this repo to my Google Cloud app engine environment; is there any way I can pull that file every 24 hours using the App Engine cron?

The app is running on an app engine.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Wow. Stack Overflow doesn't make usernames case insensitive? That's a bug, not a feature.

Comment: Hey @GAEfan, nice to meet you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  But, you have not given us enough info to help.  For instance, what language are you using?

If you have a url to a file, you can fetch that from your app.  Then, you can save that file to your GCS storage bucket and access it there from your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Build triggers](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) based on GH commits to get the updated file and trigger the app to be deployed to GAE. If the file is updated at the exact same time everyday, you can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://medium.com/google-cloud/scheduling-cloud-builds-24d821d5a3d2) to run like a cron job.